# Storing HTML in datastore and Decoding during XSL transformation

Tags: javascript, html, html-encode

I'm trying to store html object tags for video players in a datastore.  This data will be serialized and passed back to client javascript where it will be transformed and displayed in the browser to show the video.  I need to be able to htmlDecode the data so that it is evaluated properly in the browser.

Any ideas how to accomplish this in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Grab your HTML code and run through one of the methods described in [this article](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) (I had good results with `encodeURI`). When ready to use - run it through the compatible decode method

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

One of my co-workers suggested the following solution:

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

This is a set of javascript libraries to encode and decode html.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the following method?

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(...)
```

And then on the JavaScript side, use the following.

```
unescape(theEncodedHtml)
```